# Pig & Cassandra & DataStax Splits Control

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I have been using Pig with my Cassandra data to do all kinds of amazing feats of groupings that would be almost impossible to write imperatively.  I am using DataStax's integration of Hadoop & Cassandra, and I have to say it is quite impressive.  Hat-off to those guys!!

I have a pretty small sandbox cluster (2-nodes) where I am putting this system thru some tests.  I have a CQL table that has ~53M rows (about 350 bytes ea.), and I notice that the Mapper later takes a very long time to grind thru these 53M rows.  I started poking around the logs and I can see that the map is spilling repeatedly (i saw 177 spills from the mapper), and I think this is part of the problem.

The combination of CassandraInputFormat and JobConfig only create a single mapper, so this mapper has to read 100% of the rows from the table.  I call this  *anti-parallel*  :)

Now, there are a lot of gears at work in this picture, including:

- 2 physical nodes
- The hadoop node is in a "Analytics" DC (default config), but physically in the same rack.
- I can see the job using LOCAL_QUORUM

Can anybody point me in the direction of how to get Pig to create more Input *Splits* so I can run more mappers?  I have 23 slots; seems a pity to only use one all the time.

Or, am I completely mad and don't understand the problem?  I welcome both kinds of answers!

Answer (score 2):

You should set `pig.noSplitCombination = true`. You can do this in one of three places.

When invoking the script:

```
dse pig -Dpig.noSplitCombination=true /path/to/script.pig
```

In the Pig script itself:

```
SET pig.noSplitCombination true
table = LOAD 'cfs://ks/cf' USING CqlStorage();
```

Or permanently in `/etc/dse/pig/pig.properties`. Uncomment:

```
pig.noSplitCombination=true
```

Otherwise, Pig may set your total input paths (combined) to process: 1.

Comment: adding `SET pig.noSplitCombination true` did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: `SET pig.noSplitCombination true` worked for me as well while using `LOAD 'cfs://ks/cf' USING CqlStorage();` , but if i use load function like `LOAD 'cfs://ks/cf?where_clause=x%3D3' USING CqlStorage();` it always takes only one mapper. Have any idea?

Comment: @Shri Without more information on the schema it's hard to say, but it's possible that the data you're narrowing down with where_clause is simply contained in a single split.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cassandra.input.split.size to something less than 64k which is the default split size, so you can get more splits. How many rows per node for the Cql table? Can you post your table schema?

add split_size to the url paramaters

For CassandraStorage use the following parameters
cassandra://[username:password@]/[?slice_start=&slice_end=[&reversed=true][&limit=1][&allow_deletes=true][&widerows=true][&use_secondary=true][&comparator=][&split_size=][&partitioner=][&init_address=][&rpc_port=]]

For CqlStorage use the following parameters
cql://[username:password@]/[?[page_size=][&columns=][&output_query=][&where_clause=][&split_size=][&partitioner=][&use_secondary=true|false][&init_address=][&rpc_port=]]

Comment: Hi!  Here is the table:    

<pre>
    `CREATE TABLE events (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    body text,
    eventname text,
    marshaledclass text,
    time timestamp
    ) WITH
    bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
    caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
    comment='' AND
    dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
    gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
    read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
    replicate_on_write='true' AND
    populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
    compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
    compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};`
</pre>

Comment: I have tried (in vein) to override `cassandra.input.split.size` to something other than the 64k value, but nothing seems to change it.  I even added it to mapred-site.xml, but it still does not change.  I also tried to override from the pig script itself, but still no luck.

Comment: @alexLiu is there any documentation on the split_size and page_size when loading data from Cassandra in Pig? A column family with ~8 million rows is taking ~40 minutes for the first Map phase to complete, and it only ever takes a single mapper. Lowering the split_size doesn't increase the number of mappers in the initial phase, and tweaking both split_size and page_size doesn't help performance.

Comment: @nate No I am still facing the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911149/datastax-cassandra-pig-running-only-one-map 
If I do SET pig.splitCombination false its running 513 maps for any size of input even with 10 rows or with 10M rows :-(

Comment: @sudheer Your problem with 513 maps is a different question that doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 0):

setting pig.noSplitCombination = true takes me to the other extreme end - with this flag I started having 769 map tasks