# Datastax Cassandra PIG Running only one MAP

Tags: cassandra, hive, apache-pig, cql, datastax

I am using Datastax Cassandra 3.1.4 with two nodes. I am running pig with CqlStorage() with 12million rows in the table, but I find there is only one map running for a simple pig command.

I tried changing split_size in my pig relation but it didn't worked.

Here is my sample query.

```
x = load'cql://Mykeyspace/MyCF?split_size=1000' using CqlStorage();
y = limit x 500;
dump y
```

I didn't find input.split.size property in my mapred-site.xml I am assuming default split size is 64*1024

I tried `set pig.splitCombination false;`

Now its taking 513 maps for any no.of records, I tried same thing from Hive

I have connected to Cassandra from Hive and gave a simple select all query with where col1>value this table have only 10 records but still this is running 513 maps.

Please help me on this

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pig & Cassandra & DataStax Splits Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575475/pig-cassandra-datastax-splits-control)

Answer (score 1):

Try this setting:

```
set pig.splitCombination false;
```

By default, pig will [combine what it considers small splits into a single map](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/perf.html#combine-files).

Comment: Hi psanford,
My aim here is to increase no.of records to read from cassandra.
By default it reads 64k rows per map, but here it is not soo.
I have about 12 million rows, if I ser pig.splitCombination to false it is taking 513 maps.
please help me on this

Comment: My aim here is to increase no.of records to read from cassandra. By default it reads 64k rows per map, but here it is not soo. I have about 12 million rows, if I ser pig.splitCombination to false it is taking 513 maps. please help me on this, now I am trying the same in hive quering from cassandra is taking 513 maps

Comment: I guess there is some problem with cassandra properties, Please let me know If I can do from that end, because by default, PIG will combine small splits and HIVE won't.
So any time it is running exactly 513 maps if small splits or not combined.
please help me on this

Comment: after long search I got this parameter
mapred.map.tasks=513
I am not setting this any where 
I tried to set mapred.map.tasks=4 but still it is not reflecting

Comment: @sudheer I suggest opening another question regarding the 513 maps that it's taking. It's a different problem than a single map, and the single map problem has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575475/pig-cassandra-datastax-splits-control