# Hadoop Cassandra Pig - row count query runs slow with only 1 map task

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I have a 4 node Cassandra cluster which is also a hadoop cluster

When I run pig script to select and count the rows of Cassandra table - it creates hadoop job with 1 map task - and it takes long time to complete that job.

Why hadoop is not creating multiple map jobs?

Comment: found some info here - http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/number-of-map-tasks

Comment: as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575475/pig-cassandra-datastax-splits-control/28595748#28595748          setting pig.noSplitCombination = true takes me to the other extreme end - with this flag I started having 769 map tasks

Answer (score 0):

The most likely thing is that the splits generated by the hadoop input format are large enough that they cover your entire token range. Try shrinking your input split size so that more tasks will be created.

Comment: the default cassandra.input.split.size is 65K rows   - the #of rows I have is 500K+

Comment: SplitSize is Cassandra Partitions, do you have that many CQL Rows or partitions?

Comment: the table has 600K rows ...with replication factor of 3...the environment in multinode with each Cassandra node is also hadoop slave                  Also I see this in my map task log - INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: Number of splits :1537